# Center alignment of Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to know if there is an option to center a jframe to the center of the screen(monitor)?
I have tried with co-ordinates but its not exact at the center.
This is what I have:

```
 Dimension ss = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
        Dimension frameSize = new Dimension ( 800, 300 );
        frame1.setBounds ( ss.width / 2 - frameSize.width / 2, 
                          ss.height / 2 - frameSize.height / 2,
                          frameSize.width, frameSize.height );
```

PS:If the question is repeated please post the link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

`pack()` gets all the layout managers to lay out components of the GUI. The `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` centers the GUI.

Comment: no it does not get centrally aligned

Comment: @user2958963: it works well for me. Are you adding *all* components to the JFrame prior to making this call? Consider creating and posting a small example program, an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that we can check and modify.

Comment: Yes all my components are added to the frame.

Comment: By mistake I commented the setsize,I noticed the frame came at the center though the size was at its minimum

Comment: @user2958963: you should not use `setSize(...)` but rather should let your layout managers set the size of components and GUI's for you.

Comment: could you give an example of layout managers only with frames not adding any panel to it.

Comment: @user2958963: that's like asking for an example of a rainbow but only using black and white. You need to add JPanel's and such to your JFrame for the layout managers to make sense.

Comment: Simple and easy to use!